# Akka Timeout Exception: Failed to get response from actor despite overriding replyTimeout

Tags: java, scala, jms, apache-camel, akka

I am using akka version 2.2.3.
I have a messaging application that uses the Akka camel consumer pattern. I keep seeing the following errors in my log:

```
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Failed to get response from the actor [ActorEndpointPath(akka://producer-subscriber/user/subscriber)] within timeout [3 seconds]. Check replyTimeout and blocking settings [Endpoint[akka://producer-subscriber/user/subscriber?autoAck=true&replyTimeout=3+seconds]]
        at akka.camel.internal.component.ActorProducer$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(ActorComponent.scala:158)
        at akka.camel.internal.component.ActorProducer$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(ActorComponent.scala:155)
        at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction$mcVL$sp.apply$mcVL$sp(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:33)
        at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction$mcVL$sp.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:33)
        at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction$mcVL$sp.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:25)
        at scala.PartialFunction$AndThen.apply(PartialFunction.scala:181)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32)
        at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.processBatch$1(BatchingExecutor.scala:67)
        at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(BatchingExecutor.scala:82)
        at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(BatchingExecutor.scala:59)
        at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(BatchingExecutor.scala:59)
        at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$.withBlockContext(BlockContext.scala:72)
        at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$Batch.run(BatchingExecutor.scala:58)
        at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:42)
        at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:386)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

The creation of the consumer occurs in another class as follows where I pass a reference to the parent class to the consumer :

```
val subscriber = system.actorOf(Props(new Subscriber(solaceAssistant, self)), name = "subscriber")
```

and here is the consumer class itself

```
import akka.actor.{ReceiveTimeout, ActorLogging, ActorRef, Props}
import akka.camel.{CamelMessage, Consumer}
import org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.language.postfixOps
import scala.util.{Failure, Success, Try}

class Subscriber(settings: SolaceAssistant, parent: ActorRef) extends Consumer with ActorLogging {
  override val endpointUri = settings.solaceDefaults.TOPIC_ENDPOINT
  val topic = settings.solaceDefaults.TOPIC
  val marshallingService = settings.marshallingService
  override def autoAck = true
  override def replyTimeout = 3 seconds



  def receive = {
    case camelMsg: CamelMessage =>
      parent ! MessageReceived(unmarshalMessage(camelMsg))
    case r: ReceiveTimeout ⇒ parent ! MessageReceived(false)
    case err: RuntimeCamelException =>
      parent ! MessageReceived(false)
    case e: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException =>
      log.info("Time out breached")
      parent ! MessageReceived(false)
    case other: Any =>
      log.info("Other msg received")
      parent ! MessageReceived(false)

  }

}
```

Does the original parent class also have to implement receiveTimeout as apart of its receive method? Im out of ideas as to how prevent the error from occuring. I can provide more details as necessary.